# OBS RTMP to Web player

Tags: rtmp, obs

Good morning, I'm biiiiig newbie and I struggle to understand one thing

I want to stream video with e.g OBS, it supports RTMP, so I'm setting up RTMP server. It works fine, I'm able to watch it via VLC, but "web" doesn't accept this format, so I have to convert it on fly to WebRTC?

and stream it somehow again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you've already discovered a solution, but you need a server that accepts the RTMP stream, and outputs an HLS video stream.  You can then use one of many JavaScript players (like video.js) to show your video on the web.

Companies like [api.video](https://api.video) will transcode the video, and give you a "web ready" player that you can just drop onto your webpage.